# Not able to connect to postgres database using play slick

Tags: playframework, slick

I'm trying to connect to postgres via play slick.

my application conf file

```
slick.dbs.default.driver= "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = url
slick.dbs.default.db.user=username
slick.dbs.default.db.password=password
```

Normally I  connect via
val connection = DB.getConnection()

How to connect when i'm using click?

Answer (score 1):

add to your application.conf an entry like:

```
slick.dbs {
  default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
  default.db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
  default.db.url=url
  default.db.user=user
  default.db.password=password
}
```

then, to get the connection (since this config is [DatabaseConfig](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/database.html?highlight=pool#databaseconfig) format) use:

```
val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[PostgresDriver] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("slick.dbs.default")
val db = dbConfig.db
```